# Why am I getting "InvalidValueError: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

Coding a delivery service Web App using Google Map API. Haven't had a problem until I started to use multi-dem array as LatLng Reference. Now I'm getting this weird error --

"InvalidValueError: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral"

I used a similar array reference for LatLng earlier and no problem, but now that it's multi-dem array I got this weird error.

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'ConnectTest.php';

            // IF YOU'RE NOT LOGGED IN, KICK BACK TO LOGIN SCREEN
            if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])){

                header("Location:signin.php");
            }


            $servername = "localhost:3306";
            $user = "sonic_client";
            $pass = "client";
            $dbName = "sonicStrains";

            $drop = "DROP TABLE ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries";
            mysqli_query($server, $drop);

            //CREATE INDIVIDUAL DRIVER TABLE TO HOLD DELIVERIES
            $createQuery = "CREATE TABLE ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries (
                transaction_id VARCHAR(13),
                timePaid INT(11),
                username VARCHAR(30),
                user_location VARCHAR(255),
                user_lat float(10,6),
                user_long float(10,6),
                item_name VARCHAR(20),
                item_quantity float,
                driver_username VARCHAR(60),
                driver_lat float(10,6),
                driver_long float(10,6),
                on_delivery tinyint(1))";

            $created = mysqli_query($server, $createQuery);

            if ($created){

                //query the deliveries for open deliveries up untill 5 deliveries
                $queryString = "SELECT * FROM deliveries LIMIT 5";

                $query = mysqli_query($server, $queryString);

                if($query){


                    // CREATE ARRAY TO HOLD QUERY ROWS
                    $rows = array();

                    while($queryresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

                        $rows[] = $queryresult;


                    }



                    echo floatval($rows[0]['user_lat']);
                    echo"<br>";

                    //INSERT & UPDATE THE TABLES WITH DELIVERY QUERIES
                    foreach($rows as $row){



                        // INSERT INTO INDIVIDUAL DRIVER TABLE
                        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries (transaction_id, user_location, user_lat, user_long) VALUES('$row[transaction_id]', '$row[user_location]', '$row[user_lat]', '$row[user_long]')";
                        $insertExec = mysqli_query($server, $insertQuery);



                        // UPDATE MASTER LIST OF DELIVERIES SO THAT OTHER DRIVERS DONT QUERY SAME ORDER
                        $updateQuery = "UPDATE deliveries SET on_delivery=true, driver_username='$_SESSION[username]' WHERE transaction_id='$row[transaction_id]'";
                        $updateExec = mysqli_query($server, $updateQuery);



                    }

                }else{echo mysqli_error($server);}




            }else{echo mysqli_error($server);}


            if(isset($_GET['pop'])){


                array_shift($rows);
                echo print_r($rows);
            }

            echo<<<_

                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>

                        <head>

                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


                        </head> 



                        <body>

                        <div class="Banner">
                            <div class="TitleText">Sonic Strains &copy;</div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="login">Logout</div>
                        <div class="gallery" id="container">
                            <div class="map" id="mapInsert"></div>
                            <div class="navButton">Start Nav</div><div class="orderButton">Order Details</div>
                            <div class="abortButton">Abort</div><div class="confirmButton" onclick="shiftOrder()">Confirm</div><div class="disclaimer"></div>
                        </div>


                        <script>




                              function initMap() {

                                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {




                                    var initialLocation = {lat:$rows[0]['user_lat'], lng:$rows[0]['user_long']};
                                    var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapInsert'));
                                    Map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                                    Map.setZoom(13);
                                    // MAKE ANOTHER MARKER FOR THE CLIENT LOCATION
                                            var userLocation = {lat:$rows[0]['user_lat'], lng:$rows[0]['user_long']};
                                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position:userLocation, 
                                                map:Map,
                                                draggable:false, 
                                                clickable:false
                                                });
                                            marker.setMap(Map);



                                }, function(positionError) {

                                    alert('Location could not be found');
                                  },{enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 3000, maximumAge:1000});

                              } 

                              function shiftOrder(){

                                  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                  http.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                      console.log(this.responseText);

                                  }
                                  http.open("GET", "driverIndex.php?pop='pop'", true);
                                  http.send();

                              }


                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&callback=initMap" 
                            async defer></script>




                        </body>
                        </html>

_;

?>
```

Here's a peek at one element of the ref array --

```
  array(5) { [0]=> array(12) { ["transaction_id"]=> string(13) "5c2fb27078926" ["timePaid"]=> string(1) "0" ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["user_location"]=> string(44) "1301 Bataan St NW, Washington, DC 20036, USA" ["user_lat"]=> string(9) "38.907246" ["user_long"]=> string(10) "-77.037292" ["item_name"]=> string(18) "girl_scout_cookies" ["item_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["driver_username"]=> string(7) "Driver1" ["driver_lat"]=> string(8) "0.000000" ["driver_long"]=> string(8) "0.000000" ["on_delivery"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Again, I've tried to parse the lat & long with floatval() because it says it's not a number

```
  var initialLocation = {lat:floatval($rows[0]['user_lat']), lng:floatval($rows[0]['user_long'])};
```

but i get -- "floatval not defined"

Comment: What does the code served to the browser look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP variables aren't inside brackets --

```
var initialLocation = {lat:{$rows[0]['user_lat']}, lng:{$rows[0]['user_long']}};
```

Comment: Sorry, now I see that you create a "heredoc" string for the HTML. Try to do this: {$rows[0]['user_lat']} (variable between braces).

Comment: it worked. My question is why? why does one need brackets around php variables in certain* situations?

Comment: Because you are using "heredoc" string and, to print array items, is necessary to put between braces, check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on **Example 3**.

Comment: Thanks, but while the doc does give a relevant example of using brackets inside heredoc, it doesn't specifically address the use of expressing complex variables using "brackets" ie "rules governing bracket use". Only says something about double and single quotes, not brackets, unless I overlooked something.

Comment: You're welcome! You right, the usage of brackets is implicit in the doc. And is "bracket" and no "brace"...my bad...